# css overlapping content wanted

Tags: html, css, overlap

Unlike most questions about overlapping content seen here, I would actually like content to overlap!

Here is my page. Try typing "USA Riverbrooke". Returned content pushes down the map.
What css syntax can allow the returned content to slide down and overlap the map?

http://tinyurl.com/ycblkkz

Comment: Which content do you want to overlap?  I don't see any "returned content".

Comment: You see the content he wants overlapping if you search for "USA Riverbrooke".

Answer (score 2):

Make #message `position: absolute;` but also put it inside the same parent as the map, set `left: 0; top: 0;` on it, and set `position: relative;` on the parent. You shouldn't need to mess with `z-index`.

Answer (score 0):

make the #message div `position:absolute` and give it a `z-index` greater than 0. It will show up on top of the map. You should then give it a non-transparent background so it stays readable.